# Determine degree rotation in 3D space

Tags: circles, rotations

This is a programming issue. I need to understand the math before I program it though.

This is an issue that has vexed me before and I was not happy many years ago with the result. When I solved it many years ago it was in 2D and I had tight control of starting and ending locations. I used a whole bunch of if, then, else statements to determine what quadrant the final point location was in. I hated the solution.

The problem is pretty simple:

- I have points in 3D space.
- The points can be orientated in any
  orientation.
- In essence the three points are all on a single plane
  and the plane is oriented in 3D space.
- I need to judge between multiple rotated points to determine which point is rotated less than the others so I need some sense of rotation direction and distance.

[image: My three points]

I need to determine the angle of rotation in degrees or radians. Rotation can be any value between 0 - 360 degrees.

The start place can be anywhere on the 360 degree circle:

[image]

The end can be anywhere on the 360 degree circle:

[image]

The direction of rotation can be either "direction" on the circle and the plane the two lines are on can be oriented in any location in 3D space:

[image]

My programming tools can give the angle between two lines (A-B) and (A-C) of between 0-180 degrees. It has no sense of direction. If I get two points that are rotated 170 degrees one is rotated 170 degrees and one 190 degrees. I can't tell the difference between the two programatically except (in my limited way of thinking) calculating where a 170 degree rotation and a 190 degree rotation is and compare those results to the trial points to determine rotation over 180 degrees.

When I look at this in the human sense my brain can't help but orient itself perpendicular to the plane and judge rotation in clockwise or counterclockwise. This construct seems to be getting in my way in this case.

Is there a mathematical solution that I am missing here?

Comment: Use vectors to determine direction - between two points it is the subtraction of the indices multiplied by the unit vectors. Than you may use vector multiplications to get cos of angle.

Comment: @Moti - Thanks for that -  I really appreciate it. I am **really** terrible at algebra, even when I was in school. Good in geometric concepts though! Can you point me to some links to educate me on this or please add a bit more step by step?

Comment: This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ might help in understanding the vector world.

Comment: @Moti - I get " the subtraction of the indices". That produces the following vector (the light blue one with the yellow dot). [link](https://imgur.com/mNEno9c). Translated it would end up where the red arrow is. I do not understand what you mean by "multiplied by the unit vectors". I have not worked on "vector multiplications to get cos of angle". Would this be cross product or dot product? I have looked at the videos. Mind blowing. Still digesting the info.

Comment: Yes - cross and/or dot products. The multiplication by unit vectors just means the conversion of the measured distances into a vector.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define the vectors $AB$ and $AC$ by subtracting head - tail.  i.e. $\vec{AB} = B - A$ and $\vec{AC} = C - A$.  This should give you an array of three numbers.  i.e. $\vec{AB}= [x_{AB}, y_{AB}, z_{AB}]$ for each vector.

You will need the length (i.e. norm) of each vector.
We denote this as $\|\vec{AB}\|$ and $\|\vec{AC}\|$.  I assume you know how to do this.

You will need the dot product of the of the vectors which is just the component-wise multiplication of the x, y  and z elements together and then summed.

$$\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC} = x_{AB}x_{AC} + y_{AB}y_{AC} + z_{AB}z_{AC}$$

You can look that up.

Then the angle that you are looking for is:

$$ \theta = \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}}{\|\vec{AB}\| \|\vec{AC}\|} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the step by step! That was so helpful. I am off until Monday. I will be watching Kahn Academy vector and matrix stuff this weekend.

Comment: @EricSnyder, Great.  That is good stuff.  Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: This works great for half the question! It gets me an angle from 0 -180 degrees between the lines. I need to determine the angle in a single direction - clockwise or counterclockwise. That would yield results 0 - 360 degrees. I am certain that I can come up with some kind of computer logic to determine quadrants and determine from there. Is there a mathematical way to determine the same thing? Perhaps I should split into a second question?

Comment: You need the cross product to get the sine and the atan2 function to get the directional angle.

Comment: You also need to determine which direction a positive angle should be. Even with cos and sin, you need some way to tell whether an angle should be +120 or -240 for example.